# Stop processes/threads before undeploying/stop application from Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, process

It is possibly programmatically to know when the web application is undeployed/stopped from Tomcat, in Java? I need to stop some processes running, but without setting up Tomcat, only Java code?

Comment: what do you mean _without setting up Tomcat_?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Use [ServletContextListener](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). It will notify you when context is created and/or destroyed.